# foreach inside foreach and out put first foreach in array

Tags: arrays, laravel

Assume I have an `array` called (data) and inside my array I have a `foreach` on products. I need to get each of these product packages inside this (data) array.

Here is what I've tried:

```php
foreach ( $products as $product ) {
    $data[] = [
        'id' => $product->id,
        'packages' => [],
    ]

    foreach ( $product->packageId as $package ) {
        $data[]['packages'] = [
            'package_id' => $package['id'],
        ];
    }
}
```

This returns:

```
- 0 [   
  id: 977
  packages:  []
]

- 1 [   
  packages   
  package_id: 14
]

- 2 [
  packages    
  package_id: 15
]
```

I need to return something like this:

```
- 0 [   
  id: 977
  packages: [
    package_id: 14,
    package_id: 15
  ]
]
```

> Update

as @Helioarch and @albus_severus mentioned in they answers that I should create the package array first then include that into the data array

this solution will add the old array of packages in every time the products loops

For Example

- product 1 has packages [1,2,3]
- product 2 has packages [4,5,6]

in this my case here it will become

- product 1 have packages [1,2,3]
- product 2 will have packages [1,2,3,4,5,6] <- witch is wrong.

> Update 2

Here is my full code

```
foreach ( $products as $product ) {
            $sums = 0;
            foreach ( $product->packageId as $package ) {
                // Get the total existing inventory
                $pckInvSum = $package->pckInventories
                    ->where( 'expiry_date', '<', Carbon::today() )
                    ->where( 'type', 'existing' )->sum( 'amount' );
                // Get the total virtual inventory
                $pckInvVirtual = $package->pckInventories->where( 'type', 'virtual' )->sum( 'amount' );
                // create new array packages to add it to the main json
                $packages[] = [
                    'package_id'    => $package['id'],
                    'package_price' => $package['price'],
                    'unit_count'    => $package['unit_count'],
                    'existing'      => $pckInvSum,
                    'virtual'       => $pckInvVirtual
                ];
                $sums       += $package->pckInventories->sum( 'amount' );
            }
            $data[] = [
                'id'                      => $product->id,
                'product_category_id'     => $product->product_category_id,
                'child_category_id'       => $product->child_category_id,
                'child_category_two_id'   => $product->child_category_two_id,
                'child_category_three_id' => $product->child_category_three_id,
                'supplier_id'             => $product->supplier_id,
                'supplier_name'           => $product->supplier->contact_name,
                'option_category_id'      => $product->option_category_id,
                'tax_id'                  => $product->tax_id,
                'barcode'                 => $product->barcode,
                'low_price'               => $product->low_price,
                'image'                   => $product->image,
                'cost'                    => $product->cost,
                'name_ar'                 => $product->translations[0]->name,
                'name_en'                 => $product->translations[1]->name,
                'details_ar'              => $product->translations[0]->details,
                'details_en'              => $product->translations[1]->details,
                'sumInv'                  => $sums,
                'campaign'                => [
                    'id'              => $product->campaign[0]->id,
                    'product_id'      => $product->campaign[0]->product_id,
                    'price'           => $product->campaign[0]->price,
                    'purchasesLimits' => $product->campaign[0]->purchasesLimits,
                ],
                'packages'                => $packages,
            ];
```

Comment: Your `$products` object already has that structure, does it not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create the package array first then include that into the data array like so:

```
foreach ( $products as $product ) {
  $packages = [];

  foreach ( $product->packageId as $package ) {
     $packages[] = [
        'package_id'    => $package['id'],
     ];
  }

  $data[] = [
    'id' => $product->id,
    'packages ' => $packages,
  ]
}
```

EDIT:

Please try again with a revised version of the code you provide below.

```
foreach ( $products as $product ) {
    $sums = 0;
    $packages = [];

    foreach ( $product->packageId as $package ) {

        // Get the total existing inventory
        $pckInvSum = $package->pckInventories
            ->where( 'expiry_date', '<', Carbon::today() )
            ->where( 'type', 'existing' )->sum( 'amount' );

        // Get the total virtual inventory
        $pckInvVirtual = $package->pckInventories->where( 'type', 'virtual' )->sum( 'amount' );

        // create new array packages to add it to the main json
        $packages[] = [
            'package_id'    => $package['id'],
            'package_price' => $package['price'],
            'unit_count'    => $package['unit_count'],
            'existing'      => $pckInvSum,
            'virtual'       => $pckInvVirtual
        ];

        $sums += $package->pckInventories->sum( 'amount' );
    }

    $data[] = [
        'id'                      => $product->id,
        'product_category_id'     => $product->product_category_id,
        'child_category_id'       => $product->child_category_id,
        'child_category_two_id'   => $product->child_category_two_id,
        'child_category_three_id' => $product->child_category_three_id,
        'supplier_id'             => $product->supplier_id,
        'supplier_name'           => $product->supplier->contact_name,
        'option_category_id'      => $product->option_category_id,
        'tax_id'                  => $product->tax_id,
        'barcode'                 => $product->barcode,
        'low_price'               => $product->low_price,
        'image'                   => $product->image,
        'cost'                    => $product->cost,
        'name_ar'                 => $product->translations[0]->name,
        'name_en'                 => $product->translations[1]->name,
        'details_ar'              => $product->translations[0]->details,
        'details_en'              => $product->translations[1]->details,
        'sumInv'                  => $sums,
        'campaign'                => [
            'id'              => $product->campaign[0]->id,
            'product_id'      => $product->campaign[0]->product_id,
            'price'           => $product->campaign[0]->price,
            'purchasesLimits' => $product->campaign[0]->purchasesLimits,
        ],
        'packages'                => $packages,
    ];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, My bad I thought I can add the array to the first array and then full it with the for each, some times we think for complicated solutions and it's more easy.

Comment: I found you answer is very useful but still there is one issue in this solution each time the products loops it will add the old packages again and then the new one's for example in `product 1` packages is [1, 2, 3] and then in `product 2` packages is [4, 5, 6] in our loop packages in product 2 will be [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] witch is wrong it should contain only [4, 5, 6] any idea.

Comment: @YousefAltaf It seems like you didn't "reset" your array between each of your product loop. On my example do you see how i put `$packages = [];` inside the product loop. This way everytime the loop continues to the next product, the array starts empty again. Why don't you show us your updated code and we can have a look

Comment: yes of course I updated my question with full code, thought maybe you will get better idea, thanks for your effort man.

Comment: @YousefAltaf Try putting `$packages = [];` on the line right after `$sums = 0` and before the package foreach loop

Comment: btw I try this before to add `$packages = [];` on top of packages loop but this will case overwriting the array and it will display the last package only, sadly it's useless to do that.

Comment: putting $packages = []; on the line right after $sums = 0 and before the package foreach loop made the trick thanks.